# Page loading issue when click on the path in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have issue with links, When I click on the any link, in the url the path is change but the page content is not update, If I open this link with new tab it work fine. Please check on heroku at http://damp-shelf-5467.herokuapp.com with login id - hospitaladmin@gmail.com and pass - 12345678 now click on the Add new , view all, add doctor or add patient you can find the issue. I was used below code for create the action link.
`<%= link_to "Add Hospital", new_hospitaladmin_registration_path, :method => :get %>`

Comment: Can't login with the credentials you provided. Does the browser console display any errors? It sounds like it might be a Turbolinks issue.

Comment: Unable to login to your HerokuApp, Getting : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 
http://damp-shelf-5467.herokuapp.com/assets/js/pages/dashboard.js. 
Please fix this one!

Comment: Oh! please use usename - hospital1@gmail.com and pass- 12345678

Comment: At my localhost I fixed the 404 file issue. but it still not work

Comment: @user3349724 Are you using turbolinks?

Comment: Can you provide me your repos? So that i can debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
  <%= link_to 'Add Hospital', new_hospitaladmin_registration_path, 
    'data-no-turbolink' => true  %>
```

If your issue is simple add Doctor is not working then use:

```
<%= link_to 'Add Doctor', new_doctor_path %>
```

if you want to skip the turbolink then try adding below option after the path:

```
'data-no-turbolink' => true
```

Comment: It work when I first click on the link it load and change the url but not content, Now if I again press enter key on rul tab on the browser it go on the target page, otherwise it show loading image

Comment: <%= link_to 'Add Doctor', :controller => "doctors", :action => "new" %>

Comment: It's rails way to use the methods rather than this, controller: action: redirections!
please use 
<%= link_to 'Add Doctor', new_doctor_path %>

Comment: It still not work I can show you on heroku after update

Comment: show me in heroku, that way it's easy to check the issue.